# Leveling and matching exposure using CoreImage / GPUImage

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering if its possible to level exposure across a set of images using either `CoreImage` or `GPUImage`. And how would I go about that?

**Example:
Say you have 4 images, but the exposure is different on the third one. How could you level the exposure so all 4 images have the same exposure?**

One idea I had was measuring and matching the exposure using `AVCapture`, i.e. if the input image is -2.0, then simply add 2.0 using `CoreImage`.

Another idea is to implement histogram equalization..

Has anyone ever dealt with the same task before? Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CoreImage (#import ) and ImageIO (CGImage) and extract exif metadata with [EXIF Dictionary Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/EXIF_Dictionary_Keys) keys:kCGImagePropertyExifExposureTime, kCGImagePropertyExifExposureMode, kCGImagePropertyExifExposureProgram, kCGImagePropertyExifExposureBiasValue, kCGImagePropertyExifExposureIndex, kCGImagePropertyExifWhiteBalance

```
- (NSDictionary*) exifData: (NSString*) path {  

NSDictionary* dic   =   nil;
NSURL* url          =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];  

if ( url )  
{
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL ((CFURLRef) url, NULL);

    if (source != nil)
    {
        CFDictionaryRef metadataRef = 
        CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex (source, 0, NULL);  
        if (metadataRef)   
        {  
            NSDictionary* immutableMetadata = (NSDictionary *)metadataRef;  
            if (immutableMetadata)
            {
                dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary : (NSDictionary *)metadataRef];
            }
            CFRelease ( metadataRef );
        }
        CFRelease(source);  
        source = nil;  
     }
 }

return dic;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSDictionary* dic = [self exifData: path];  
if (dic)
{  
    NSString *s = [dic valueForKey: kCGImagePropertyExifExposureTime];  
    NSLog(@"Image : %@ - ExposureTime : %.2f", path, [s floatValue]);  
}
```

And then changing the exposure or white balance with:

```
- (UIImage *) changeImageExposure:(NSString*) imagename exposure:(float) exposure {  
   CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: imagename]];
   CIFilter *exposureAdjustmentFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust"];
   [exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
   [exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exposure] forKey:@"inputEV"];
   CIImage *outputImage = exposureAdjustmentFilter.outputImage;
   CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
   return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this example!! One question though, how would I apply this to level the images exposures? Let's say I have an array with 4 images. Would I just loop through the array? Or what approach do you recommend?

Comment: yes just loop through the array, using ImageIO or directly with AVCapture as you suggested.

Comment: Okay, so basically save the first exposure setting and then apply that to the rest of the images?

Comment: no, per new image if you use AVCapture, since the user might moved to a different place (e.g. different exposure) or clouds in front of the sun etc.
But if you use existing images the just loop.

Comment: Yeah, so save the first image exposure then apply to rest of the images? If not, how do I know what value to apply to the rest of the images?

Comment: If you add one new image at a time, then you just need to add this in one place (e.g. when saving the image), since every new image will run the same code, so no loop is needed then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118485/discussion-between-filip-and-gillsoft-ab).